# restart matlab window button motion after a temporary disabling

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am designing a Matlab GUI. In this GUI, windowButtonMotion constantly takes input. However, I need to stop it for a little while and ask the user a visual input from another figure. This figure closes after the input and the programme is supposed to work the same way.

I disable the WBM with this code when the new figure pops up:

```
set(fighandle, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', '');
```

The question is, how can I restart the WBM after input is taken.

I do not call the WBM with a function call like:

```
set(fighandle, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @fun);
```

In the contrary, I write the codes under the `windowButtonMotion_Fcn` callback in the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to *store* the callback before you change it and then you can reset it to the same thing. This will work regardless of *what* your callback is.

```
% Store the original
originalCallback = get(fighandle, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn');

% Disable the callback
set(fighandle, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', '')

% Do stuff

% Now reset it
set(fighandle, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', originalCallback)
```

If these do not happen within the same function, you can store the previous callback within the figure's app data.

```
% Get original callback and store within the appdata of the figure
setappdata(fighandle, 'motioncallback', get(fighandle, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn'));

% Disable the callback
set(fighandle, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', '')

% Then from another function re-enable it
set(fighandle, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', getappdata(fighandle, 'motioncallback'))
```

Your other option is to actually open your second figure as a modal figure and then the mouse interaction with the background figure will be ignored. Then you will not have to tamper with the `WindowButtonMotionFcn`.

```
fig2 = figure('WindowStyle', 'modal');
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is good, but I found another way that works well and is a little bit simpler for my situation:

Basically, I just set the figure I don't want to interact with to be invisible temporarily using:

```
set(fig_handle, 'visible', 'off')
```

In my situation, it takes several seconds to do all the set up and computations while setting up the figures and if someone happens to move the mouse over the figure as this is all being set up, the windowbuttonmotionfcn will give an error, so I just set the figure to invisible until all the setup is done, then do this:

```
set(fig_handle, 'visible', 'on')
```

This may or may not be what you want to happen in your situation.